# Qt EvdevTouch plugin alterning coordinates

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, qt5.5

I have an embedded Qt application that used to be able to interface with my touch-screen just fine using the EvdevTouch plugin but for some reason it has now started to alter the coordinates received from the driver in a very strange fashion.

In order for me to now get something close to the actual Y coordinate of a touch I have to calculate it as:

```
y = y + (y / 640 * 150)
```

I should mention though that this is actually the x coordinate coming from the screen because my scene is rotated 90 degrees.

I can confirm that the Linux driver is fine looking at the evtest output and when I run the application through xinput rather than evdevtouch then the coordinates are also correct. I don't want to use xinput though because it doesn't work as nice as EvdevTouch used to for multitouch.

PS. My Qt build is the latest one on the Jethro branch of meta-qt5 (5.5) for Yocto.